# Centos 7 Apache 2.4 php_fpm 30 second timeout

Tags: centos, proxy, php-fpm, apache-2.4, timeout

I need to set execution timeout for Centos 7 Apache 2.4 php_fpm, but there seems to be a hard coded timeout somewhere in the Apache proxy.  I see max_execution_time correctly set (to 300) in php_info().

I've tried the virtualhost fix proposed elsewhere for Apache 2.2 like so:

```
 ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9009/var/www/$1
 <Proxy fcgi://127.0.0.1:9009>
       ProxySet timeout=300
 </Proxy>
```

Trying reversing order on those to put the  line first, which I saw in one example, led to an error on service httpd restart.   I tried setting request_terminiate_timeout to 0 or to 300 or to 300s in the php-fpm config file, as well as same for request_slowlog_timeout.  Still have a hard coded 30 second timeout somewhere.

Help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054827/intensive-php-script-failing-w-the-timeout-specified-has-expired-error-ap-c/22518620#22518620

Answer (score 1):

Easier solution for me is to adjust Apache's ProxyTimeout directive
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this thread](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/bugs/429391) I found a method that worked for me.

Putting the timeout and connectiontimeout= on the same line as the ProxyPassMatch works like so:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9009/var/www/$1 timeout=3600 connectiontimeout=3600
```